# Head First Rails | NoMethodError in Ads#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm studying Head First Rails Ch2, and I use rails 4.
After I entered localhost:3000/ads I got an error as following

NOMethodError in Ads#index
Showing /Users/changfengTSAI/mebay4/app/views/ads/index.html.erb where line #3 raised:
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Here's what i did for this exercise

1.rails new mebay4

2.rails g model ad name:string description:text price:decimal seller_id:integer email:string img_rul:sting

3.rake db:migrate

4.rails g controller ads

5.ads_controller.rb

```
def show
  @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
end
def index
  @ad = Ad.find(:all)
end
```

6.routes.rb

```
get 'ads/' => 'ads#index'
get 'ads/:id' => 'ads#show'
```

7.index.html.erb

```
<h1>All ads</h1>
<ul>
  <% for ad in @ads %>
  <li><a href ="/ads/<%= ad.id %>"><%= ad.name %></a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I would like to know how to solve this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index
  @ads = Ad.find(:all)
end
```

The variable naming is wrong.